# What is the difference between 旦, 夕 and 汐?

Tags: meaning, kanji

I'm struggling to get the difference between 旦, 夕 and 汐 - to me them all signifies "evening". Is that so? Do they mean the same thing?

I'm not a native speaker of english, so please give me a clear explanation if there is any difference at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kanji are usually explained like this:

- **夕**: A very easy joyo kanji that means **"evening"**.
- **旦**: A relatively uncommon joyo kanji that originally means **"morning"**, but this original meaning is largely forgotten. For details, see: [Heisig story #30 (Nightbreak) 旦, shouldn't it mean "daybreak" instead?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26016/5010)
- **汐**: A *non*-joyo kanji that means **"tide"** (strictly speaking, it meant "evening tide", but this meaning is obsolete). It appears in several place/person names and scientific terms, but it's a rare kanji otherwise.

So only 夕 means "evening". Please check if you are using correct learning resources. (Seriously, is your source really about *Japanese*?)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. 
Actually I'm using Heisig's book lol. I had the same problem that OP from your linked question had. 
About the last kanji, read https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eventide have cause to me some misunderstanding.
I'm really grateful.

Comment: Just to confirm, 旦 really means "morning" even if it meaning is forgotten, right?

Comment: Wait... so what is the difference between 旦 and 朝 ? Does 旦 means "dawn" (when the morning is starting)?

Comment: I knew it! I owe my kanji recognition skills to Heisig's RTK, but do note that he tends to use less common meanings of kanji as keywords. Be careful of that. By the way, have you just started RTK? @Mycroft

Comment: @rebuuilt I'm on kanji 120, but I'm accepting more material suggestions

Comment: @Mycroft I used Anki along with this deck: https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1862058740

When I was studying for JLPT N3, I suspended all JLPT N1 kanji. This is so that I can focus on the more common characters. After passing N3, that's when I studied JLPT N1 kanjis.